# how to configure struts in eclipse galileo?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts

i've included jars in class path and i've created struts-config in web-inf bt it is giving the following error:

servlet action is not available

Comment: http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html

Answer (score 1):

- right click on project
- select new ->
- select servlet
- while creating, select existing servlet
- select superclass as ActionServlet
- specify mapping as param name = config and param value = /web-inf/struts-config.xml
- select name as action
- edit url mapping as *.do

and go.....